# Doctrine2.1: Finding by DiscriminatorColumn results in "Unknown field" exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've tried to search for this error but the fact that I haven't found anything leads me to believe that I'm doing something silly. I'll include the relevant code below, but basically I'm using multiple table inheritance (or [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)) and trying to use the Doctrine ORM findBy() method to query based on the discriminator column, which results in the following ORMException being thrown: "Unrecognized field: type".

Here is the code that triggers the exception:

```
    // $this->em is an instance of \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    $repository = $this->em->getRepository('JoeCommentBundle:Thread');

    return $repository->findOneBy(array(
        'type' => $this->type,
        'related_id' => $id
    ));
```

Here is the relevant code for the 'base' abstract entity:

```
<?php

namespace Joe\Bundle\CommentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment_threads")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {"story" = "Joe\Bundle\StoryBundle\Entity\StoryThread"} )
 */
abstract class Thread
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="related_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $relatedId;

    /** MORE FIELDS BELOW.... **/
```

And finally, here is the code for the concrete thread entity:

```
<?php

namespace Joe\Bundle\StoryBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Joe\Bundle\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread as AbstractThread;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="story_comment_threads")
 */
class StoryThread extends AbstractThread
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Story")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="story_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $story;
}
```

I've double checked my schema, and the `type` column definitely exists, so I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Doctrine should take care of mapping that "type" column for you. I'm wondering if its a reserved keyword and maybe causing some issues. Try changing to something else and see if you still get the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lee, but changing it to "thread_type" didn't make any difference. Luckily this forced me into fixing my local xdebug and I can now see that there is a check in 'Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister' on line 1205 like so: "if (isset($this->_class->columnNames[$field]))". The $this->_class->columnNames array doesn't contain the discriminatory column (as 'type' or 'thread_type') BUT there is a $this->_class->discriminatorColumn array that contains the details I'm after. Is this a bug in Doctrine as it isn't being considered?

Comment: I've done a little more digging and found the following issue report from almost 2 years ago: [http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-707](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-707) It has been marked as a duplicate of a resolved bug, but I think the actual issue has been overlooked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rob, when querying your actually using the parent entity and trying to filter on the discriminator value. Instead, work on the repository relative to the child entity you want to fetch. Doctrine will do the rest for you. So in your case you want to get the repository for **StoryThread**.

```
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('JoeCommentBundle:StoryThread');
return repository->find($id);
```

Comment: This works also in symfony 2.8? empty response for me

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use the discriminator column as a standard entity property.

Instead you may do the following:

```
$dql = 'SELECT e FROM JoeCommentBundle:Thread e 
    WHERE e.related_id = :related_id AND e INSTANCE OF :type';
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameters(array(
    'type' => $this->type,
    'related_id' => $id
));
$record = $query->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Ah I see, I'll be sure to keep that in mind. As it turns out it was easier to just use the find methods of the relevant repository though.

Comment: Sometimes it's not enough. For example, if you need to select 2 of 3 entity types or even order by the type.

Comment: FYI: You can select on multiple types using `INSTANCE OF (:type1, :type2, ...)` so you don't have to concatenate multiple `INSTANCE OF` function calls for each class you want to include in the result.

Comment: Could not find any reference for this feature in documentation. Can you?

Comment: @Gedrox See: [The initial Doctrine2 feature request that resulted in `INSTANCE OF` (Doctrine Issue Tracking System)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-482?focusedCommentId=13699&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13699)

Comment: For "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8": /vendor/doctrine/orm/docs/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.rst